# Different content same page

Tags: android

I have an application to display quotes one after another. The page format is same but every time just the content changes. And accordingly the buttons for previous and next pages. Is there a way to do it using xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Bellow Example:

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
 <Button android:onClick="onClickNext"

android:layout_width="fill_parent"


android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Click"
/>

<TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
```

Your ACtivity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

private TextView tv;
private String data[4];
private int i = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

tv = (TextView) findViewById(r.id.extView1)
data[0] = "hello";
data[1] = "hi";
data[2] = "bye";
data[3] = "fine";
}



public void onClickNext(View v)
```

{

```
if(i<data.length)
{
tv.setText(data[i]);
i++;
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

Define your view with a text view and the two buttons, and use the `setText` method on the text view to change the text.

Inside your activity, you want something like this:

```
public void onNextButtonClicked(View view) {
    TextView myView = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
    myView.setText("My next text");
}
```

Inside your layout XML, something like this would set up the event binding:

```
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/nextButton"
    android:onClick="onNextButtonClicked"
    android:text="@string/next_button"/>
```